# Get specified input from user in Facebook Messenger Bot

Tags: node.js, facebook-messenger

Can someone tell me how I can trigger a form field for my Facebook Messenger Bot?

**What it should look like:**

> Bot: Please enter your E-mail
>
> User:  email@adress.com
>
> Bot: Email saved in database

I want to trigger this as an event, and not permanently listen for an e-mail

Comment: What's your starting point? Do you have some code to show us? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

I am not really sure about what you want, but if I understand a bit you can use something like this :

```
var re = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
app.post('/webhook', function (req, res) {
    var events = req.body.entry[0].messaging;
    for (i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
        var event = events[i];
        if (event.message && event.message.text) {
            if(re.test(event.message.text)){
                //call your handler function here
            }
        }
    }
    res.sendStatus(200);
});
```

Note that I use regex here, you can probably use a simpler function if you don't need a precise verification.